# Yii2 Yii::$app->request->userIP is not giving right IP address under ELB

Tags: php, yii2

I am unable to get User IP address in Yii2 application inside [ELB](https://searchaws.techtarget.com/definition/elastic-load-balancing) but without ELB its working fine. I have also try below code

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
   $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
```

but this is also failed sometime, below is the error

```
ERROR 1 => The value "223.190.123.220, 66.102.6.83" is not a valid IP address.
ERROR 2 => The value "2402:3a80:10d3:e19f:e7e1:8c35:fb4a:b49c, 66.102.6.89" is not a valid IP address.
```

It will be better if someone suggest me any solution within Yii2.

Comment: Setting `$trustedHosts` property of `yii\web\Request` component to contain range of IPs that ELB uses might help. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$trustedHosts-detail

Answer (score 1):

use this function it will help you

```
  public function RealIP() {
    $ip = false;
    $seq = array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'
        , 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED'
        , 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP'
        , 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'
        , 'HTTP_FORWARDED'
        , 'REMOTE_ADDR');

    foreach ($seq as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false) {
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks your help bro, your answer is good for me but why we have check all sequence ? User IP should be in REMOTE_ADDR, Why ELB IP address is coming in REMOTE_ADDR ?. Actually I am looking for an optimized option that why I am curious about these things